SIP Call error: pjmedia_endpt_create_base_sdp: Assertion `!"Invalid address family"' failed
I am a college student who is new to VOIP and SIP. I have a SIP server setup and am able to register myself, but when I try to make a call, there is this error:

10:43:18.461            pjsua_acc.c  ..Acc 0: Registration sent
10:43:18.461           pjsua_call.c  Making call with acc #0 to
sip:132@172.10.0.151 10:43:18.461          pjsua_media.c  .Call 0:
initializing media.. softphone: ../src/pjmedia/endpoint.c:935:
pjmedia_endpt_create_base_sdp: Assertion `!"Invalid address family"'
failed. Aborted

This is the piece of code that I think is the problem:
// Make a call with audio disabled
    CallOpParam prm(true); // Pass true to indicate this is an outgoing call
    prm.opt.audioCount = 0; // Disable audio

    // Debugging info for call setup
        try {
            MyCall *call = new MyCall(acc);
            call->makeCall("sip:133@192.168.123.80", prm);
            cout << "*** Call setup completed ***" << endl;
        } catch (Error &err) {
            cout << "Error during call setup: " << err.info() << endl;
        }

(I have disabled the audio because there were permission errors and no audio device errors)
